# Create date/time when the format is unknown

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a small application which imports several CSV files from different sites. Each site have their own format for date. Some of the formats are below.

```
  '2013-12-04 11:32:21 +0000'
  '04/12/2014 +0000'
  '04/12/2014 +0000 11:32:21'
  'Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014'
```

I need to convert above formats into simple format like `'d-m'Y'`. The problem here is that the formats aren't known in advance and I can't go and change the code every time a new CSV files needs to be added to system.

Is there a way using which I can convert all these formats into simple format? I've tried below but it doesn't work and I can't find any other solution.

```
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat(strtotime('2013-12-04 11:32:21 +0000'), '2013-12-04 11:32:21 +0000'); 
  print_r($date->format('d-m-Y')); //Doesn't work
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for your comment and sorry for the trouble. From Golez's comment I mange  to find the bug that was creating recursion and manage to solve it.

Comment: It's okay. One other approach is to add the necessary extra detail in the question after you've solved it, request its reopening, and then add a self-answer. In some cases this might help someone else (though I don't know Zend well enough to say whether this is a common error with the Validator module). Pleased you solved it!

Comment: @halfer. Thanks, will keep in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP understands *a lot* of date formats. It's not required to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` here. Simply pass your date string to the `DateTime` construct and format it on the go:

Example:

```
$array = [
  '2013-12-04 11:32:21 +0000',
  '04/12/2014 +0000',
  '04/12/2014 +0000 11:32:21',
  'Fri Mar 14 18:19:26 +0000 2014',
];

foreach ($array as $datestr) {
    $dt = new DateTime($datestr);
    echo $dt->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2013-12-04
2014-04-12
2014-04-12
2014-03-14
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/145313)

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$date = new DateTime('2013-12-04 11:32:21 +0000');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //2013-12-04 11:32:21
```

Read manual :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

if you want all to convert create an array of values and pass in datetime your values