# Creating PHP DateTime when format is unknown

Tags: php, datetime

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422915/create-date-time-when-the-format-is-unknown), I have been able to parse a date string into a `DateTime` object, then display it in the desired format. The `DateTime` constructor works well in deciphering `DateTime` strings with one (very understandable) exception - it cannot tell the difference between `dd/mm/YYYY` and `mm/dd/YYYY`.

If I do the following:

```
$dt = new DateTime("05/03/1900"); // 5th march 1900
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then I get the following output:

```
1900-05-03
```

However, the original date is in `dd/mm/YYYY` format, so my output is incorrect - I now have the `3rd May 1900`.

Is there a way to set `DateTime` to prefer `dd/mm/YYYY` over `mm/dd/YYYY` when parsing a date string?

*Edit:*
I am calling `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` in the constructor of this class but this doesn't seem to have any effect. Perhaps this isn't linked to the `DateTime` class.

Comment: For timezone: `DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', '05/03/1900' , new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));`

Comment: The DateTime object is like `strtotime()`

It assumes the date is USA format if you use `/` as a seperator and European if you use `-` as a seperator.

Comment: If the format is unknown, then you can NOT reliably parse it. what's to say that your date is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy? The `/` hints that it's a US format, but nothing says it HAS to be. that's either march 5th, or may 3rd. you cannot tell.

Comment: @MarcB I am instructing the user that the timestamp should be `dd/mm/yyyy`. My versions of chrome and firefox have slightly different date inputs and provide me date strings in different formats. Therefore I need to handle both. Chrome, I know for sure will be `dd/mm/yyyy`. Firefox, on the other hand, will be `yyyy/mm/dd`, which I need to parse and convert. It is this parsing process that is causing confusion.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Using `DateTime::createFromFormat` does not seem to return a `DateTime` value. When I then try and call `format()`, I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean`

Comment: @BrianButterfield Then you are doing something a little wrong, show us the code you wrote (in your question)

Comment: @BrianButterfield Then you need to valiadte that form before you store it. Eg. use select dropdowns for years, for month, and for days.

Comment: @MarcB There is chrono-node for JS that does just that. Why can't there be a library like that for PHP then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', '05/03/1900' );
echo $dt->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```

Comment: Add the timezone please.

Comment: This was actually my first attempt before using the `DateTime` constructor. However, this seems to return a boolean instead of a `DateTime` object, as I then get the error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean`

Comment: @BrianButterfield If you are getting a boolean it means the function is failing. Double check the formatting you are passing in with the date you are passing in to ensure they are the same format.

Comment: What about the "when format is unknown" requirement in the title?

Comment: This will only work when you know what the format being passed is.