# How to fetch the hours,minutes,second,am/pm from the string in php?

Tags: php, android, mysql

i want to separate the time into hours,minutes,seconds,am/pm , which is stored in the database under the name `starttime(varchar)` as 1:00pm.

[image: This is my mysql database]

How to separate the start time into hours,minutes,seconds,am/pm in `php`,and i need to send them to android activity.can anyone help me to do this.

this is my php code

```
    <?php 
error_reporting(0);
require "init.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];



$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info` WHERE `name`='".$name."' AND `password`='".$password."';";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

$response = array(); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    //$response = array("id"=>$row[0],"name"=>$row[1],"password"=>$row[2],"email"=>$row[3],"ScheduleDate"=>$row[4],"StartTime"=>$row[5],"Endtime"=>$row[6],"Hours"=>$row[7]);

    $response = array("id"=>$row[0],"StartTime"=>$row[5],"Endtime"=>$row[6],"Hours"=>$row[7]);

    }

echo json_encode(array("user_data"=>$response));

?>
```

Android activity code

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name, password;
    String Name, Password;
    Context ctx=this;
    String NAME=null, PASSWORD=null, EMAIL=null,ScheduleDate=null,StartTime=null,Endtime=null,Hours=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_name);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_password);
    }



    public void main_login(View v){
        Name = name.getText().toString();
        Password = password.getText().toString();
        BackGround b = new BackGround();
        b.execute(Name, Password);
    }

    class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String password = params[1];
            String data="";
            int tmp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://localhost/sample/loo/text.php");
                String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
                os.flush();
                os.close();

                InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                    data+= (char)tmp;
                }

                is.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return data;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            String err=null;
            try {
                JSONObject root = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONObject user_data = root.getJSONObject("user_data");
                NAME = user_data.getString("name");
                PASSWORD = user_data.getString("password");
                EMAIL = user_data.getString("email");
                ScheduleDate = user_data.getString("ScheduleDate");
                StartTime = user_data.getString("StartTime");
                Endtime = user_data.getString("Endtime");
                Hours = user_data.getString("Hours");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                err = "Exception: "+e.getMessage();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, Home.class);
            i.putExtra("name", NAME);
            i.putExtra("password", PASSWORD);
            i.putExtra("email", EMAIL);
            i.putExtra("ScheduleDate", ScheduleDate);
            i.putExtra("StartTime", StartTime);
            i.putExtra("Endtime", Endtime);
            i.putExtra("Hours", Hours);
            i.putExtra("err", err);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd take a step back and ask whether it is possible to store the StartTime in a DateTime field instead of as a string. Instead preprocess the data to be saved in an easy to use format.

Comment: yes, sir,but they have created the database like this only, they stored the starttime and endtime in varchar,so only i am asking,how to seperate them?

Comment: This could be tricky because it appears that users are able to put whatever they want into the `StartTime` field. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23422915/create-date-time-when-the-format-is-unknown) to see how to convert many common date time strings. It won't cover all cases but it is a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
   try {
        String StartTime = "10:30 am";
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
        Date date = null;
        date = sdf.parse(StartTime);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfH = new SimpleDateFormat("hh");
        String hours = sdfH.format(date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfM = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");
        String minutes = sdfM.format(date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfS = new SimpleDateFormat("ss");
        String second = sdfS.format(date);
        SimpleDateFormat sdfA = new SimpleDateFormat("aa");
        String ampm = sdfA.format(date);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**O/P**

```
Time:  10  30  AM  00
```

I Hope help for you